# Linux - List users which have specific directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script which will list the name of the user, only if that specific user has a specific and available directory in his folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f5\,6 | cut -d : -f2`
do
        cd $i
        if [ -d public_html ]
        then
                echo `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f5,6 | cut -d : -f1`
        fi
done
```

First, I get a list of all the user names that have home folders.
Then, for each user, I enter in his directory
If in his directory, public_html directory is found, echo the user.

When I run this in the terminal, all the users are listed:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f5,6 | cut -d : -f1
```

However, I need to somehow get the user i from that whole list.

Can anybody be so kind to explain what I´m doing wrong, and what to look out for?

Comment: Note that on modern Linux systems it is common for users not to have entries in /etc/passwd (e.g. because they are managed by LDAP), so this approach won't work in general.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the wrong result because you're checking for a file (with `-f`). Try using `-d`. 
Using cat and cut is not bash either and can easily be replaced with script in most cases.

I'd do something like this:
`while IFS=: read -r user pass uid gid desc homedir shell; do [ -d "$homedir"/public_html ] && echo "$user"; done < /etc/passwd`

We set the field separator (`IFS`) to `:` (since that's what `/etc/passwd` uses), we read the file in and set the variables we want to use.
Then for each line we do the test and (`&&`) if the test is successful we echo the result.

The quotes are not really necessary since we know the formatting of the file but good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If users' home directories are set up in the standard way:

```
cd /home
for pubdir in */public_html/ ; do
    echo "${pubdir%%/*}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this returns a "*" and nothing else

Comment: You must not have permissions to list the contents of the /home directory, or your users' home directories may not be in the standard place.  This approach will not work for you.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I did it ghetto style...

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
for i in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f6`
do
        if [ -r $i ]
        then
                cd $i
                if [ -d public_html ]
                then
                        counter2=2
                        for j in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f5`
                        do
                                counter2=$(($counter2 + 1))
                                if [ $counter -eq $counter2 ]
                                then
                                        echo $j
                                fi
                        done
                fi
                counter=$(($counter + 1))
        fi
done
```

Comment: In bash4 you can new increment a counter like this too: `count=0;while IFS=: read -r user pass uid gid desc home shell; do [ -d "$home"/public_html ] && echo $user && let "count++"; done < /etc/passwd; echo $count`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
getent passwd | awk -F: '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1, $6}'| while read -r user home
do
  if [ -d ${home}/public_html ] ; then
    echo ${user}
  fi
done
```

This should work irrespective of use of /etc/passwd or ldap ...